# Continue the number sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Some minor misunderstanding last week inspired me on creating this puzzle. Hope it would be not very boring :)

Sequence:

> 10 50 100 306 356 562 ...

What`s next?

**Hint:**

> RUR

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> 612 ?

Why I think so:

> the given numbers in binary are:
> 1010
> 110010
> 1100100
> 100110010
> 101100100
> 1000110010
> So the next would be:
> 1001100100 which in decimal equals 612
>
> However, it would look nicer if the 10 was left out or replaced by 12 (1100) (assuming I'm not totally mistaken with my guess)

Edit: I found a second pattern (with the same outcome)

> In hexadecimal numbers we get:
> (A)
> 32
> 64
> 132
> 164
> 232
> and finally 264

Bonus:

> RUR = Rossum's Universal Robots

Answer (score 0):

After the first digit, the sequence goes

> with an alternate difference of 50 and 206

As

> 100-50=50
>  306-100=206
>  356-306=50
>  562-356=206 and so on

The next number will be

> with a difference of 50.